# Docker install failed on raspbian with "BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch."

Tags: raspbian, apt, docker

I have tried to install docker on the latest rasbian:

```
Uname -a
Linux mypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

but I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aufs-dkms aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount cpp-4.6 dkms gcc-4.6 libltdl7 linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi linux-kbuild-3.6
  linux-kbuild-4.9 pigz
Suggested packages:
  aufs-dev gcc-4.6-locales python3-apport menu libmudflap0-4.6-dev gcc-4.6-doc libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libquadmath-dbg libmudflap0-dbg
  libcloog-ppl1 | libcloog-ppl0 libppl-c4 libppl12 | libppl9 binutils-gold
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aufs-dkms aufs-tools cgroupfs-mount cpp-4.6 dkms docker-ce gcc-4.6 libltdl7 linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi
  linux-kbuild-3.6 linux-kbuild-4.9 pigz
0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14,3 MB/38,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 169 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf pigz armhf 2.3.4-1 [50,0 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf dkms all 2.3-2 [74,8 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf linux-kbuild-4.9 armhf 4.9.51-1+rpi3 [671 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf aufs-dkms armhf 4.9+20161219-1 [169 kB]
Get:5 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf aufs-tools armhf 1:4.1+20161219-1 [101 kB]                                    
Get:6 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf cgroupfs-mount all 1.3 [5.716 B]                                              
Get:7 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf cpp-4.6 armhf 4.6.4-5+rpi1 [4.145 kB]                                         
Get:8 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf gcc-4.6 armhf 4.6.4-5+rpi1 [4.363 kB]                                         
Get:9 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common armhf 3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7 [4.189 kB]   
Get:10 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf linux-kbuild-3.6 armhf 3.6-1~experimental.1+rpi2+b2 [136 kB]                 
Get:11 http://ftp.tugraz.at/mirror/raspbian/raspbian stretch/main armhf linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi armhf 3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7 [414 kB]       
Fetched 14,3 MB in 45s (316 kB/s)                                                                                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package pigz.
(Reading database ... 37325 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-pigz_2.3.4-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking pigz (2.3.4-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../01-dkms_2.3-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-kbuild-4.9.
Preparing to unpack .../02-linux-kbuild-4.9_4.9.51-1+rpi3_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking linux-kbuild-4.9 (4.9.51-1+rpi3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aufs-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../03-aufs-dkms_4.9+20161219-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking aufs-dkms (4.9+20161219-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package aufs-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../04-aufs-tools_1%3a4.1+20161219-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking aufs-tools (1:4.1+20161219-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cgroupfs-mount.
Preparing to unpack .../05-cgroupfs-mount_1.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking cgroupfs-mount (1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-4.6.
Preparing to unpack .../06-cpp-4.6_4.6.4-5+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-4.6 (4.6.4-5+rpi1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libltdl7:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libltdl7_2.4.6-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libltdl7:armhf (2.4.6-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
Preparing to unpack .../08-docker-ce_18.03.0~ce-0~raspbian_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (18.03.0~ce-0~raspbian) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-4.6.
Preparing to unpack .../09-gcc-4.6_4.6.4-5+rpi1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-4.6 (4.6.4-5+rpi1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common.
Preparing to unpack .../10-linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common_3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common (3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-kbuild-3.6.
Preparing to unpack .../11-linux-kbuild-3.6_3.6-1~experimental.1+rpi2+b2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking linux-kbuild-3.6 (3.6-1~experimental.1+rpi2+b2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi.
Preparing to unpack .../12-linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi_3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi (3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7) ...
Setting up aufs-tools (1:4.1+20161219-1) ...
Setting up cpp-4.6 (4.6.4-5+rpi1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.6-trunk-common (3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7) ...
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.3) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-2) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-4.9 (4.9.51-1+rpi3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u2) ...
Setting up libltdl7:armhf (2.4.6-2) ...
Setting up gcc-4.6 (4.6.4-5+rpi1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up linux-kbuild-3.6 (3.6-1~experimental.1+rpi2+b2) ...
Setting up pigz (2.3.4-1) ...
Setting up docker-ce (18.03.0~ce-0~raspbian) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-04-01 11:12:27 CEST; 37ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 21340 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 21340 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 562ms

ápr 01 11:12:27 mypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
ápr 01 11:12:27 mypi systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up aufs-dkms (4.9+20161219-1) ...
Loading new aufs-4.9+20161219 DKMS files...
It is likely that 4.9.80-v7+ belongs to a chroot's host
Building for 3.6-trunk-rpi, 4.14.30+ and 4.14.30-v7+
Building initial module for 3.6-trunk-rpi
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Skipped.
Module build for kernel 4.14.30+ was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Module build for kernel 4.14.30-v7+ was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up linux-headers-3.6-trunk-rpi (3.6.9-1~experimental.1+rpi7) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.6-trunk-rpi
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I install docker on this rasbian?

Do I need to downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this error on my rpi3 with stretch installed. I downgraded to jessie, and followed the tutorial here: 
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/#upgrade-docker-ce-1
using the convenience script, and everything worked fine.

I am not sure what might have caused it fail on stretch, i read somewhere else that it was due to missing headers or smth like that, im not sure.